# Building a generic block-based CMS with Django

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-orm

A designer recently handed me designs for a site I'm building for a client. They're great designs but I'm really scratching my head as to how I'm going to implement it on the site.

The content can very easily be broken down into blocks or chunks of data where I could allocate a textarea for text input, a couple of charfields for link-buttons, etc and sequentially render them out to the page.

The problem (eg why I'm not just pulling in Django-CMS et al) is the blocks are quite unique from each other. There are perhaps 20 different models that I would build for each block type. Rather than hack around a pre-fab CMS, I'd like to build a Page model and then just have an M2M that links to an ordered list of subclasses of my abstract Block class. I hope I'm not losing you.

I don't understand how I can do this. These questions spring to mind:

- Is there a simple CMS that does all of this already? Am I wasting my time trying to figure out the physics?
- My Blocks subclasses will technically be  different type. Do I need generics for a M2M-through class to link to them? Is so, how do I do that?
- How do I render x different forms in an inline admin context? (I'd like to have the page form with a list of the Blocks underneath)
- How can the user specify the type of Block in the inline control?

---

### Edit: Or, alternatively, what about a templatetag-based CMS?

I'm thinking of something like plonking this in my template:

```
{% editable 'unique_id' 'content-type' %}
```

A further example:

```
{% editable 'home-intro' 'text' %}
```

Then I could just stick these around the templates I want to be editable, in the way I want them to be editable and when logged in the client would see "Edit text", "Edit link", "Edit image" links which simply popped up the right field.

This would make things more locked down but the layout needs to remain solid (and the client knows nothing about HTML/CSS) so it's one or other of these methods IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you implement your 'Blocks' as Django CMS Plugins? Then each page is just constructed from a number of plugins.

Each plugin has an admin form which gets the specifics for itself, and then the page template renders the plugin as you want it.

If you look at the first page of the django-cms demo:

https://www.django-cms.org/en/tour-demo/

you'll see in (1) a highlighted plugin block - in this case a formatted text block that is edited with TinyMCE or similar. You can define your own plugins and add them to pages.

Comment: I could (and have actually done this for a different client in the past) but there's an awful lot of faff in that and I'm not hugely keen on their interface. That's been my excuse for not using it for this project but I do realise that what I'm suggesting might incur even more faffing around than just pulling in Django CMS. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

last month I published an article (for review) on how tho build a basic CMS for Jinja. This's templating language does not dffer very much from Django, which I have been using before.
You can find it here. It uses template inheritance to fill the content blocks.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5965/review-request-jinja-cms-for-energiekantoor-nl-on-google-app-engine
Or type in Google : Jinja CMS